# Pass An ArrayList<CustomObject> to a function that accepts as parameter an ArrayList<Object> in Java

Tags: java, android, generics, arraylist

I am writing a generic java-android function that will accept as one of it's parameters an `ArrayList<Object>`, so that I can use all over my application regardless of the type of the ArrayList elements.

This is my function:

```
public GenericDisplayAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Object> arrData) {

    this.m_ArrData = arrData;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

When I try to to pass my `ArrayList<CustomObject>` as a parameter to this function, I get the error "can't cast from `ArrayList<CustomObject>` to `ArrayList<Object>`",

```
        m_LVStructDamageHeader.setAdapter(new GenericDisplayAdapter(
            (Activity)this, (ArrayList<Object>)arrStructDamageHeaders));
```

What is the best approach to handle such a situation, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your function from

```
public GenericDisplayAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Object> arrData)
```

to

```
public GenericDisplayAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<?> arrData)
```

Then you will be able to pass `ArrayList<T>` for any `T`. `ArrayList<?>` is almost like `ArrayList<Object>`, but the difference is that while you can add *ANY* object into the `ArrayList<Object>` (which is pretty bad if you pass e.g. `ArrayList<CustomObject>` there), you cannot add anything into the `ArrayList<?>` (which is fine).

Comment: "cannot add anything..." except `null`

Answer (score 2):

change the method parameter

```
ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<? extends Object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider also, that it may be appropriate to give the GenericDisplayAdapter class a type parameter.  E.g.

```
class GenericDisplayAdapter<T> {
    private List<T> m_ArrData;

    public GenericDisplayAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<T> arrData) {
        ...
    }
}
```

So then other methods can take advantage of this type parameter, instead of dealing in Object, they can use T.

Answer (score 1):

You should you generic ArrayList just like

```
public GenericDisplayAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<?> arrData) {

    this.m_ArrData = arrData;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```